# How to specify a document as type of parameter in XSLT stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a parameter in a XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:param name="OVERRIDE_CONFIG" required="yes" />
```

The `OVERRIDE_CONFIG` parameter is to provide another XML document to load.

I am able to pass in a file location from the command line using Saxon parser successfully using:

```
...  +OVERRIDE_CONFIG=u:/config/override_config.xml
```

and the transform is working.

I'm still trying to figure out if there a way to specify the type of the parameter using `as` attribute?  I tried

```
<xsl:param name="OVERRIDE_CONFIG" as="document" required="yes" />
```

but I get an error that it is not a recognized atomic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `as="document-node()"` for the attribute, the syntax of sequence types used in XSLT 2.0 is defined in the XPath 2.0 specification https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-sequencetype-syntax.

Comment: Or if you want to be more precise, you could write as="document-node(element(invoice))"/> to require the outermost element to be named "invoice".